# Minimum Deletions to Make String Balanced

Tags: c++

[Minimum Deletions to Make String Balanced - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-deletions-to-make-string-balanced/)

> 1653. Minimum Deletions to Make String Balanced
>
> Medium
>
> You are given a string `s` consisting only of characters `'a'` and `'b'`​​​​.
>
> You can delete any number of characters in `s` to make `s` **balanced**. `s` is **balanced** if there is no pair of indices `(i,j)` such that `i < j` and `s[i] = 'b'` and `s[j]= 'a'`.
>
> Return *the **minimum** number of deletions needed to make* `s` ***balanced***.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> **Input:** s = "aababbab"
> **Output:** 2
> **Explanation:** You can either:
> Delete the characters at 0-indexed positions 2 and 6 ("aababbab" -> "aaabbb"), or
> Delete the characters at 0-indexed positions 3 and 6 ("aababbab" -> "aabbbb").
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> **Input:** s = "bbaaaaabb"
> **Output:** 2
> **Explanation:** The only solution is to delete the first two characters.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> - `1 <= s.length <= 105`
> - `s[i]` is `'a'` or `'b'`​​.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int minimumDeletions(string s) {
        int cnt=0;
        stack<int> st;
        st.push(s[0]);
        for(int i=1;i<s.length();i++){
            if(s[i]=='b'){
                st.push(s[i]);
            }
            else{
                if(st.empty()==true){
                    st.push('a');
                }
               else if(st.top()=='a'){
                    st.push('a');
                }
                else{
                    while(st.empty()==false and st.top()=='b'){
                        cnt++;
                        st.pop();
                    }
                    st.push('a');
                }
            }
        }
        return cnt;
    }
};
```

for both the exapmles the answer should be 2,2
but my code it giving 3,2

Comment: Step through the program with the debugging utility that came with your development tools and keep an eye out for where the program deviates from your expectations.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to learn some test framework. IMO two best are:

- gtest - industry standard - old but quite powerful
- catch2 - nice and more user friendly, quickly gains popularity.

Write test code which will validate your solution then use it with a debugger to find issue in your code.

Here is an example with catch2:

https://godbolt.org/z/xevvPrEeK

```cpp
TEST_CASE("Sum") {
    auto [result, s] = GENERATE(table<int, std::string>({
        { 0, ""},
        { 0, "a"},
        { 0, "b"},
        { 0, "ab"},
        { 1, "ba"},
        { 1, "bba"},
        { 1, "baa"},
        { 1, "aba"},
        { 2,  "aababbab" },
        { 2, "bbaaaaabb" },
    }));
    INFO("s = " << s);
    REQUIRE(result == Solution{}.minimumDeletions(s));
}
```

Note this test finds simplest case where your code fails.

On problem: use of the stack is obsolete. Just try find place where you have to delete all `b`s before it and all `a`s after it.